# libxml2 - failure to parse valid xml

Tags: c++, libxml2

I have a small C program using libxml2 for parsing xml files. Basicaly, my code is like

```
xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseFile("test.xml");
if (doc == nullptr) {
    return;
}
xmlNodePtr node = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
if (node == nullptr) {
    return;
}
...
```

I'm getting an error situation, where doc != null and node == null. Under which conditions could that happen? I've tested with completely valid, invalid, and empty files, it happens in every case. If file does not exist, doc == null (as it should). I suspect that the program is not able to open the file for some reason, but I've checked rights, and no other program uses that file. Also, this only happens in an environment, where I cannot use a debugger.

Comment: it may happen if the xml file exists but is empty, because the current directory you're running from is different from the one where you run it without issue... check current dir

Comment: Can you use the xmllint tool that comes with libxml2 with the --debug flag to see what libxml2 thinks the in-memory DOM looks like for the document? Maybe that'll shed some light. There might be some other options that would allow you to dig deeper.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think that it's a problem with paths, because the behavior is different depending on if the file exists. Can the executable location be an issue even if using absolute paths? I've tested with same file in both environments.